# add-content : The input object cannot be bound to any parameters for the command either because

Tags: powershell

I am trying to generate a text file with output I need to build in a for each statement but I get this error:

> add-content : The input object cannot be bound to any parameters for
>   the command either because the command does not take pipeline input or
>   the input and its properties do not match any of the parameters that
>   take pipeline input.

What am I missing here?

```
foreach($item in $filteredItems)
{
    $user = $web.EnsureUser($item)
    if (-Not $profileManager.UserExists($user.LoginName))
    {
        $loginName = $user.LoginName.Substring(13)
        #Write-Host $loginName
        $userFromAD = Get-ADUser -Filter {SAMAccountName -eq $loginName}
        $concatenatedUser = $user.ID.ToString() + ";#" + $userFromAd.Name
        #Write-Host  $concatenatedUser
        $query = [String]::Format("<Where><Contains><FieldRef Name='Persons_PDB' LookupId='True'/><Value Type='LookupMulti'>{0}</Value></Contains></Where>",$user.ID)
        $userItemsQuery = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPQuery
        $userItemsQuery.Query = $query
        $userItemsQuery.ViewAttributes = 'Scope="Recursive"'
        $userItems = $list.GetItems($userItemsQuery)
        #Write-Host "Numer of items found: " $userItems.Count
        foreach($item in $userItems)
        {
            #Write-Host $userFromAd.Name
            if([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($userFromAd.Name)){
                $output = "Person not in AD, file will be deleted:"+ $item.File.Name 
                write-output $output | add-content D:\Installers\PictureDB\R 1.0\Scripts\Add-ArtifactsToWeb\usernotinAD.txt
            }
```

Comment: Hi you can try out-file -Append ? i think this can be work at you want   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-file?view=powershell-6    or other way you can try add " " to the file path name

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are having space in your path and PS is not able to pick it up. Also, write-output will display the output directly in the terminal and will not pass it to the pipeline object. I have modified it accordingly. I am not going through the logic that you have put together since you are getting issue only on the output part of it.

**Change this:**

```
write-output $output | add-content D:\Installers\PictureDB\R 1.0\Scripts\Add-ArtifactsToWeb\usernotinAD.txt
```

**To:**

```
$output | add-content "D:\Installers\PictureDB\R 1.0\Scripts\Add-ArtifactsToWeb\usernotinAD.txt" -Force
```

Hope it helps.